WinUI: PropertyChanged handler in viewmodel is null
I have this win ui main window which assigns a viewmodel and binds to a property. the text is displayed correctly initially from the viewmodel, but when the viewmodel updates the text, the control is not updated. i found out that the eventhandler of the propertychanged event in the viewmodel is always null, as it the ui didn't subscribe to it. what am i missing here?
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.ViewModel = new AdventureViewModel();
    }

    public AdventureViewModel ViewModel { get; }
}

<Window
    x:Class="Adventure.WinUi.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Adventure.WinUi"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Text}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>


ok i found the answer, the default binding mode of winui is OneTime, so I have to set it to OneWay when it is to be updateable:
   <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Text, Mode=OneWay}" />

